# $\operatorname{sconv}(A)=\left\{ \sum_{i=1}^\infty\lambda_i\cdot a_i:a_i\in A, \lambda_i\ge0,\sum_{i=1}^\infty\lambda_i=1\right\}$ is superconvex

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, convex-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $A\subset X$ a subset bounded.

Denote by $\operatorname{sconv}(A)$ the superconvex hull of $A$:

$$\operatorname{sconv}(A)=\left\{ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\lambda_i\cdot a_i:\;\;a_i\in A\;,\;\lambda_i\ge0\;,\;\sum_{i=1}^\infty \lambda_i=1\right\}$$

A set $A$ is superconvex if $\operatorname{sconv}(A)=A$

How can we prove that: $\operatorname{sconv}(A)$ is superconvex

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you use \displaystyle when an actual _display_ would accomplish the same thing and it's in a place where a display would be appropriate?

Comment: Let $B=\mbox{sconv}(A)$. Clearly $B$ is bounded and $B\subseteq \mbox{sconv}(B)$. The point is in the reverse inclusion. But that's just some summation swapping made legal by absolute convergence.

Comment: Swapping is not right word. The key is that $\sum_i\lambda _i=1$ and $\sum_j\mu_{ij}=1$ for every $i$ yields $\sum_{i,j}\lambda_i\mu_{ij}=1$ (with nonnegative coefficients). And $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}\simeq \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: How is super convex defined? Countable collection rather than finite?